# How change the phpize to match the php version?

Tags: 16.04, php, xdebug

I have a php version of `7.1.1`, and the `phpize` I installed by following the instructions from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php is like this,

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
```

when I searched about this, it is for `php 7.0`

Is there a way I can change this? I followed this instruction https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize but still not working.

Answer (score 12):

In Ubuntu 16 Vagrant box with multiple versions of PHP installed and having PHP7.1 as default. I ran the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

In my case

`php -v` showed version `7.2`, and

`php-config --version` showed version `7.0`

---

My **solution** was to run:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev`

so that versions match

---

And now running
`php-config --version` shows `7.2` properly

And running `phpize` shows:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
```

(changed from `20151012` to `20170718`)

Answer (score 2):

I found that running the specific version of phpize and php-config which matched the php version (7.2) solved my compilation issues:

```
$ /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/phpize
$ ./configure --enable-shared --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-config
```